# pyqtgraph cuts off tick labels if showGrid is called

Tags: python, plot, pyqt5, visualization, pyqtgraph

I am attempting to show some subplots using `pyqtgraph`.
I would like to set x and/or y axis limits and a grid on these plots.
Here an example without the grid:

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg


x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)


app = pg.mkQApp()

win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show = True)

p1 = win.addPlot(row = 0, col = 0)
p1.plot(x = x, y = y, pen = pg.mkPen(color = 'b', width = 1))
p1.setXRange(0, 2*np.pi, padding = 0)
p1.setYRange(-1, 1, padding = 0)

app.exec_()
```

[image]

If I turn on the grid with:

```
...
p1.showGrid(x = True, y = True)
app.exec_()
```

then I get:

[image]

As you can see in the bottom left corner, x and y first ticks are cutted off and this issue shows up only when I turn on the grid.
How can I show the grid on my plots (and set properly x and y limits) without cutting off axis tick labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue appears to have been created in attempt to fix another detailed here on github: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/732

In the pyqtgraph/AxisItem.py source, if you hash out the below two lines (1162, 1163) the issue is corrected, but artifacts will show on the axis again:

```
# Draw all text
if self.style['tickFont'] is not None:
    p.setFont(self.style['tickFont'])
p.setPen(self.textPen())

# bounding = self.boundingRect().toAlignedRect()
# p.setClipRect(bounding)        # Ignore Clip
for rect, flags, text in textSpecs:
    p.drawText(rect, int(flags), text)
```

Another option, as listed on the github issue link, would be to  only show axis ticks that fit the bounding box (overwrite in AxisItem.py source):

```
# Draw all text
if self.style['tickFont'] is not None:
    p.setFont(self.style['tickFont'])
p.setPen(self.textPen())

bounding = self.boundingRect()
for rect, flags, text in textSpecs:
    # PATCH: only draw text that completely fits
    if bounding.contains(rect):
        p.drawText(rect, int(flags), text)
```

My preferred method though has been to set the grid via the 'top' and 'right' axis and disable it from 'left' and 'bottom', where the tick labels reside.  Give this a try:

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)

app = pg.mkQApp()
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show = True)

p1 = win.addPlot(row = 0, col = 0)
p1.plot(x = x, y = y, pen = pg.mkPen(color = 'b', width = 1))
p1.setXRange(0, 2*np.pi, padding = 0)
p1.setYRange(-1, 1, padding = 0)

p1.showGrid(x = True, y = True)
p1.getAxis('left').setGrid(False)      # Disable left axis grid
p1.getAxis('bottom').setGrid(False)    # Dsiable bottom axis grid

for key in ['right', 'top']:
    p1.showAxis(key)                            # Show top/right axis (and grid, since enabled here)
    p1.getAxis(key).setStyle(showValues=False)  # Hide tick labels on top/right

app.exec_()
```

Resulting plot: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRdro.png)

On line 581 of pyqtgraph/AxisItem.py source you can see how the tick bounding rectangles are handled differently if 'self.grid' is True or False:

```
def boundingRect(self):
    linkedView = self.linkedView()
    if linkedView is None or self.grid is False:
        rect = self.mapRectFromParent(self.geometry())
        ## extend rect if ticks go in negative direction
        ## also extend to account for text that flows past the edges
        tl = self.style['tickLength']
        if self.orientation == 'left':
            rect = rect.adjusted(0, -15, -min(0, tl), 15)
        elif self.orientation == 'right':
            rect = rect.adjusted(min(0, tl), -15, 0, 15)
        elif self.orientation == 'top':
            rect = rect.adjusted(-15, 0, 15, -min(0, tl))
        elif self.orientation == 'bottom':
            rect = rect.adjusted(-15, min(0, tl), 15, 0)
        return rect
    else:
        return self.mapRectFromParent(self.geometry()) | linkedView.mapRectToItem(self, linkedView.boundingRect())
```

Comment: I edited my code according to your suggestions and now everything works fine! Thank you so much! :-)